# Play Framework 2.4.0 unit-testing issue

Tags: unit-testing, playframework

My problem is as follows:

I am trying to test multiple unit-tests in my controller in a Play Framework 2.4 application. I figured out I need to use a FakeApplication to run the FakeRequests to my controllers in, but for some odd reason the unit-tests work if I start and stop a **new** FakeApplication. If I start and stop the **same** FakeApplication, the first unit-test with a FakeRequest works, and the rest dont.

**My question:**

What am I doing wrong? Why are my unit-tests working if I start and stop a new FakeApplication, and why are they not working if I start and stop the same FakeApplication?

**Here is my code snippet:**

> UnitTest class:

```
@Test
public void submitTestCorrectInput() {

    final String input = CORRECT_INPUT;
    final Result result = doCall(input);

    assertThat(result.status(), is(equalTo(Http.Status.OK)));
}

@Test
public void submitTestIncorrectInput() {

    final String input = INCORRECT_INPUT;
    final Result result = doCall(input);

    assertThat(result.status(), is(equalTo(Http.Status.NOT_FOUND)));
}

private Result doCall(final String input, final String max, final String filter) {

    final Http.RequestBuilder requestBuilder = Helpers.fakeRequest(routes.Application.submit(input));

    return route(requestBuilder);
}
```

> Superclass from unittest class:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    Play.start(Helpers.fakeApplication().getWrappedApplication());
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
    Play.stop(Helpers.fakeApplication().getWrappedApplication());
}
```

Comment: Which Play version do you use?

Comment: 2.4.0 - it's in the subject title

Comment: Looks fine to me. Maybe, if you doing something fancy in the Global class you should give your fakeApplication() in setUp() an instance of your Global:  `GlobalSettings global = (GlobalSettings) Class.forName("common.Global").newInstance();` and `Helpers.fakeApplication(global);`.

Comment: Someone edited my post. The problem I'm having, is that the code mentioned above works. I dont understand why. The function Helpers.fakeApplication() returns a new instance of the FakeApplication. So in theory it shouldnt work. If the function returns a new FakeApplication, shouldnt the Play.stop and Play.start stop and start a new instance instead of the same?